# Cannot Assign to 'Money' Because It Is a 'Method Group'

Tags: c#, function, class, methods, method-group

I'm doing a project for class, and I have to call the `Money` function from my `Player` class. However, I do not know how to change `Money` into something else that is not a `Method Group`. I don't know much programming, so my range of solutions is rather small.
Also, the instructor said I cannot make any changes to the `Main` class, only to the `Player` class.

Here's the code for the `Main` class:

```
 p1.Money += 400;
```

And here's the 'Money' function from my Player class:

```
public int Money ()
    {
        return money;
    }
```

Comment: `Money` is a method, it will return something. You need to call it like `p1.Money()` and then assign the result back. Something like `p1.SomeProperty = p1.Money() + 400;`

Comment: It sounds like you want a *property* or a *field*. You might need to start with some basics of C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Money()` is a method. You can't set it - it only returns something (an `int`) (or nothing if `void`).

You need to change it to a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) that can also be set:

`public int Money {get; set;}`

or, more elaborative:

```
private int _money;
public int Money { get { return _money; } set {_money = value;} }
```

Comment: You know, I started to problem solve going through my professor's lectures and code samples, and I came up with the same exact thing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
money += 400;
```

or change the Method to a property,

```
public int Money {get;set;}
```

Depending on the context of where you are trying to do the increment (in class or in a class that uses the Money property (field)