# Cannot assign to ' ' because it is a 'method group' beginner

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I'm practicing on setters and getters, got this error message:

> Cannot assign to 'GetnewName' because it is a'method group'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bird b = new Bird();
            b.GetnewName = "Tweety";
            b.Chirp();

            Bird b2 = new Bird();
            b2.GetnewName = "Woody";
            b2.Chirp();
        }
    }
    public class Bird
    {
        private string name;
        private double weight = 30.5d;

        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            if (newName != null && newName.Length > 2)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Bird already has a name");
                this.name = newName;
            }
            else if (newName.Length < 3)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("New name must be longer than two chars");
            }
            else
            {
                name = newName;
            }
        }

        public string GetnewName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

    public void Chirp()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(name + " says chirp!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetnewName` is neither a getter nor a setter nor even a property -- it's a method. And you can't assign a value to a method. Read up on the topic of properties; getters and setters should follow naturally.

Comment: `GetnewName` is a method, not a property. You can only call functions, you can't assign values to them.

Comment: In C#, you don't write methods as setters and getters (unlike Java). You can, but that is a messy way to go about things. Instead, we typically use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Assign to 'Money' Because It Is a 'Method Group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164043/cannot-assign-to-money-because-it-is-a-method-group)

Comment: @gunr2171 i want to have access to 'private string name;' with get and set how to do it from my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set name using the SetName method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bird b = new Bird();
            b.SetName("Tweety");
            b.Chirp();

            Bird b2 = new Bird();
            b2.SetName("Woody");
            b2.Chirp();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Bird
    {
        private string name;
        private double weight = 30.5d;

        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            if (newName != null && newName.Length > 2)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Bird already has a name");
                this.name = newName;
            }
            else if (newName.Length < 3)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("New name must be longer than two chars");
            }
            else
            {
                name = newName;
            }
        }

        public string GetnewName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void Chirp()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(name + " says chirp!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While that works in some sense, it's not how this code would typically be written in C#. Using explicit (non-property) getters and setters would be considered an anti-pattern in most code bases.

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert's commet above, you should be using properties here.. but with your code as it is now.. the error is caused because you tried to use GetnewName  instead of SetName.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert this is what i wanted, is this wrong ? if it is why it is working ?

Comment: I'm not sure if "wrong" would be the correct term. If it works, it's the right way. -- However, it may not be the best practice as there are more acceptable and sustainable approaches.

Comment: @waleedd32 its not that its wrong... maybe best to say its not best practice.  see dasblinkenlight's answer to see how the code can be improved.  if you use c# properties you significantly improve the readability of the code for one thing...

Comment: this is not actually using setters and getters here ? because when i remove gets and sets from the code it still works like setter and getter, name is private but still accessible when removing set and gets. @psj01

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a string to a method, this causes the error.
I c# we don't use getters and setters as in Java or C++. Instead we have *properties* which we use. You can assign and read values as if they where fields but they have special methods called *accessors*. You should refactor your class like this:

```
public class Bird
{
    private string name;
    private double weight = 30.5d;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bird already has a name");
                name = value;
            }
            else if (value != null && value.Length < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("New name must be longer than two chars");
            }
            else
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Chirp()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(name + " says chirp!");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
var bird = new Bird();
// assign a value (equivalent to SetName method in your original code)
bird.Name = "Woody";
// read a value (equivalent to GetName method in your original code)
Console.WriteLine(bird.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `GetnewName` as if it were a [*property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), but you defined it as a pair of methods.

Property syntax combines the getter and the setter under a single name. Then C# re-routs assignments to the setter, and reads to the getter method:

```
public string Name {
    get => name
    set {
         if (value != null && value.Length > 2) {
             System.Console.WriteLine("Bird already has a name");
             name = value;
         } else if (value.Length < 3) {
             System.Console.WriteLine("New name must be longer than two chars");
         } else {
             name = value;
         }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `get => name` above uses the new syntax. Old syntax for the same was `get { return name; }`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you want this:

```
public string Name 
{
    get; private set;
}
public void SetName(string newName)
{
    if (newName != null && newName.Length > 2)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Bird already has a name");
        Name = newName;
    }
    else if (newName.Length < 3)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("New name must be longer than two chars");
    }
    else
    {
        Name = newName;
    }
}
```

The `get;` will automatically return the value of your property, without the need for a private backing property, and typically you could use the setter inside the property to set the value, but since you need to pass a parameter too it, it seems like making the setter private and creating a separate method to actually set it would suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.